# Merge two appsrc pipelines into 1 MPEG-TS Stream

Tags: python, c++, c, gstreamer, pygobject

I'm trying to get some custom KLV metadata mux'ed into my live video stream.  I recently learned that ideally, you have a metadata stream and a video stream, then mux them together into a single transport stream.

Here is my launch string for my video stream pipeline:

```
self.video_launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc pass={} quantizer={} speed-preset={} tune={} byte-stream=true ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host={} port={} sync=true'
```

Here is my launch string for my klv stream:

```
self.meta_launch_string = 'appsrc name=klvstream is-live=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME caps=meta/x-klv,parsed=true ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host={} port={} sync=true'
```

How would I go about creating one MPEG-TS Stream from these two appsrc pipelines?

The current behavior I am seeing from running these two seperately is the video makes it to the client, seemingly without data.  I assume this is becuase they aren't actually muxed together.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I got a pipeline together that merged my video and metadata into one MPEG-TS stream.

```
mpegtsmux name=mux alignment=7 ! udpsink host={} port={} sync=false
appsrc name=source is-live=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc pass={} quantizer={} speed-preset={} tune={} byte-stream=true ! mux.
appsrc name=klvstream is-live=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME caps=meta/x-klv,parsed=true ! mux.
```

Two things to note:

- sync=false was a must. (Edit: Turns out its not a must, but the stream seems more performant)
- for video frame outputted, there must also be a metadata buffer outputted.  Video buffer and metadata buffer timestamp, duration, pts, dts and offset should be equal. (Unsure if this is a must, but my video player whined a lot about dropped metadata packets if these were not equal).

Comment: thanks for share the pipeline,I have implement a python version but when i want reproduce the video, show "meta/x-klv decoder error...". Any suggestion? https://gist.github.com/All4Gis/509fbe06ce53a0885744d16595811e6f